# google author not working for my site

Tags: search-engine

I have a website:

http://www.radhanath-swami.info/mysterious-intervention-of-the-divine-will/

I have added everything properly. Even in my google+ contribute. Still it says author not working

```
      Cannot verify that rel=author markup has established authorship for this webpage.
      First rel=author link from webpage: https://plus.google.com/106983158048716170972?rel=author
      Link (direct or indirect) from website to Google+ profile: Yes
      Public contributor-to link from Google+ profile to www.radhanath-swami.info: No
      Note: The testing tool currently only checks the first rel=author link listed on a webpage for a link to a Google+ profile (https://plus.google.com/106983158048716170972?rel=author). It's possible that authorship may in fact be working for this page because of other rel=author links on the page. To verify that authorship is working on this page, please ensure the first profile listed on the site links to the appropriate Google+ profile.
      Other rel=author links from page:
      https://plus.google.com/106983158048716170972
      http://www.radhanath-swami.info/radhanath-swami/
      https://google.com/+RadhanathSwamiMaharaj?rel=author
```

Comment: I am trying to figure it out, but You need to add me on google plus So I can see the needed information. Also be aware that you're posting you G+ we usually discourage posting emails and this is kinda similar

Answer (score 1):

I mean, just removing the link and placing it in placing it in the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004f1bd2dd012cc9eff9486f5459786) It didnt like the Authorship link, but it looks like there is the nescessary "Contributor" link on your G+ page.

On the flipside, plugging in the web URL directly, I get [this](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.radhanath-swami.info%2Fmysterious-intervention-of-the-divine-will%2F) and it works! So, I would recommend having Google fetch the page, or just wait for them to crawl it again because it seems to work now.

If you continue to have problems you can try troubleshooting more [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/troubleshooter/2483183#ts=2483184,2483189,2483766,2613284). [This](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1093493)  Also is for troubleshooting why you rich snippets won't work.

You can also try making sure that profile Discovery is turned on in G+ settings: "Help others discover my profile in search results" [plus.google.com/settings](https://plus.google.com/settings)

Sorry, this is really just a bunch of links. Everything on your page looks to check out to me (authorship link) and it looks like you have the nescessary